# What tool for easily cutting cardboard is child-safe?

Tags: tools

What is a child-safe (for a 10 year old) tool to cut cardboard (~1/4" thick, from a typical cardboard box)?

EDIT:
I'd like the child (who is fairly responsible) to be able to use this independently for a lot of cutting.  I don't feel comfortable with leaving her with a box cutter (also her 8 yo sister might then get access to it). Also *I* don't find box cutters to be terribly easy to use when making precise cuts.

I found three:

- [Klever Cutter](http://www.kleverinnovations.net/kleverkutter.html#blank) (cost is about $3 ea. but I suspect they don't last long. Can't replace the blade.
- [Skil powered cutter](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001B64ZEE) (downside: expensive and a bit more dangerous)
- [Powered scissors](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000BAURWU)  - (Downside: I think they'd be pretty slow)

Comment: Not to be that guy, but I don't see the problem with using a box cutter or exacto knife so long as you're supervising. I definitely handled an exacto knife at that age, with my mother hovering all-too-uncomfortably close over my shoulder.

Comment: How many kids, and how much cutting is going to be happening?

Comment: Over [on Parenting](http://parenting.stackexchange.com/q/2975/1324) the OP indicates that it's a single child, his daughter, and that there will likely be a lot of cutting long-term, as she's pretty "crafty" and likes to build things.

Comment: Re-open.  Teaching children how to use tools safely is one of the biggest improvements to your home an lifestyle you can make.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*[Please see [the revised and expanded version of this answer at Parenting Stack Exchange](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/2975/what-would-be-a-good-kit-for-cardboard-construction-projects-for-a-pre-teen/2976#2976).]*

When I was the age to be cutting holes in cardboard boxes for fun, the tool I had was a serrated knife — I think it was sold as a very cheap steak knife. The blade was, basically as dull as a letter opener (and somewhat flexible), but the serrations made it quite effective at cutting cardboard like a saw, either neatly or roughly depending on the force applied. It did have an end pointy enough to require some care, but that was never a problem that I recall.

It also makes a great noise when cutting a large panel, especially the side of a box, as the cardboard vibrates.

I don't have any specific product recommendations as this was a few decades ago.

Comment: You can also get plastic serrated knives.

Comment: I tried a plastic serrated knife and it didn't work very well, but a metal one might work well.